# validate two different dates in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript function for date validation.The function is given below.

```
function IsValidDate() { 
    if (Date.parse($("#startdate").val()) <= Date.parse($("#enddate").val())) {
        return true;
    } 
    else { 
        return false 
    }
}
```

Here I have two date pickers and I am just validating whether the start date is less than or equal.

Now I want to modify the method to validate whether the selected start date and end date range is equal to 3 or not. If its greater than 3 i need to show an alert message.

How to achieve this. Can any one help?

Comment: "is equal to 3 or not" ... 3 what?

Comment: are you using a plugin for datepickers?

Answer (score 2):

[Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) parses a string and returns the number of milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970.

You can check if the differences between the 2 returned values is lesser than or equal to the total number of milliseconds in 3 days, which is `259200000 == 3600000 * 24 * 3`

```
function IsValidDate() { 
    var from = Date.parse($("#startdate").val()), to = Date.parse($("#enddate").val());
    if(to - from > 259200000) { // greater than 3 days
        alert('greater than 3 days');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```